# Created custom shipping method in magento2, but can not save addtional data

Tags: jquery, magento, magento2

I have created a module in magento2 to add custom shipping method. Shipping method is added and i have added additional form with custom shipping method.

I am new to magento 2 so no idea how to save these additional details in quote and order.

[See image form is added with custom shipping method need to save this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s2W7.png)

Comment: i want to do the same in my magento 2 website, can you please give me an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue has been resolved and additional data needs to be saved using extension attributes in magento 2.Using extension attribute data can be saved and transferred to next state where it can be saved permanently using observers.

Comment: hi how did you manage to do this.Can you please explain your module